# Is Cron the only method to run scheduled tasks?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

Is cron(or its derivatives) the only method to run scheduled programming tasks? For example:

1. Charge clients' credit card at 3 days before X
2. Send e-mail 6 hours from time x
3. Execute xyz command every hour

Is there any good resource/books to teach how to implement these features in a clean way(python, ruby(or ROR), python)?

My current dirty method is to have a wrapper script in CronTab running every minute to check if certain tasks should be run. I don't really like this. I prefer a method where I can programatically implement scheduled tasks.

Comment: If you're using a database, it might support `events`

Comment: RoR gem: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: thanks about the suggestions. How robust is Rufus-scheduler?

Comment: I would say look at the [number of issues](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues) and the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/rufus-ruby) for any complaints. The one thing to be aware of is that if RoR is not running, your tasks will not run...

Comment: There's also this: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

Answer (score 3):

For python you can use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

For example executing command every hour will  look like this:

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=3))
def every_three_hour():
    print("This runs every three hour")
```

And execting three hours from now will look:

```
from datetime import datetime

YourTask.apply_async(args=[some, args, here], eta=datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`at`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29)might be more appropriate if you want to schedule one-off jobs at specified times in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No you ca set schedule job using linux something like this we did

```
if (strtoupper(substr(php_uname(), 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
       // This is for Windows
       $cmd = PHP_PATH . " " . PATH_CLASS . "/Cron/somecron.php";
       pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
       unset($_SESSION['something']);
   } else {
      //This is for Linux
      exec("php " . PATH_CLASS . "/Cron/somecron.php > /dev/null &");
      unset($_SESSION['something']);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Ruby/ROR's `delayed_job`, more info [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Very easy to setup, and most important - active project which is weapon of choice for most of Rubiest that I know :)